# Dynamic Div objects in web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to have a div display a certain amount of orange circles per a changing variable. How would this be done?

If the number is 4, there should be 4 orange circles.
If the number is 3, there should be 3 orange circles..

Additional, Animating exit and entrance?

Whats the best way to do this in a web app? THANKS!

Example code/jsfiddle would be amazing. :)

Comment: I see. And is there anything else you would like us to do as well? Shine your shoes perhaps?  Questions must be specific and must show that you have attempted to solve the problem for yourself first.  Don't ask lazy questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#number').keyup(function(){
      $('#container').empty();
      for(var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++){
          $('#container').append('<div class="circle">&nbsp</div>');
      }
  });

});
```

```css
.circle {
   width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

change this value:
<input id="number" type="text" value="3">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help and time!